Много процессов /usr/sbin/mysqld и /usr/sbin/httpd
htop показывает много процессов /usr/sbin/mysqld и /usr/sbin/httpd
И с каждым днем по немного забивается Mem, что с этим стоит делать?


Не процессов, а потоков. Так и должно быть

а /usr/sbin/httpd?

А его количество процессов вы сами регулируете в его конфиге (количество потоков mysql, впрочем, тоже можно регулировать)

@andreymal подскажите пожалуйста, что такое /usr/sbin/httpd?

Если вы не знаете, какие программы вы ставили на своём собственно сервере, то это грустно. Apache это, да и слово bitrix в имени пользователя жирно намекает
